# Any way to get news image thumbnails from bing-api news items?

Tags: json, bing-api

Is there any way to get thumbnails that go along with news items using the bing api?  bing.com has images for each news item (http://www.bing.com/news?q=games for example) and you would think the api would have this feature too.

Answer (score 0):

I searched on internet and there is no help on this. 
I found embed.ly as an alternative that I could implement. But the results along with Thumbnail from Bing would have been of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use their RSS API that has them

http://www.bing.com/news?q=&format=RSS